# How do I avoid automatic reconnection when QuickFix/J fails to connect?

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

Imagine a scenario the connection IP becomes unreachable. In this case, QuickFIX/J will try to reconnect automagically every 30s or so, as configured by parameter `ReconnectInterval`. How do I avoid such behavior?

Answer (score 4):

Your application class should extend `ApplicationExtended` instead of `Application`. Then you can override [canLogon](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/javadoc/1.6.1/quickfix/ApplicationExtended.html#canLogon(quickfix.SessionID)) method and if you return false, Quickfixj will not try to login.

Answer (score 0):

The idea consists on retrieving parameter `ReconnectInterval` from QuickFix/J and create a separate thread which is going to kill the `Session` if and only if the `Session` is not logged on yet.

In order for this to work, our thread must obviously be fired before the QuickFix/J thread tries to reconnect. In other words: if you configured `ReconnectInterval=30` ... you have to fire the aforementioned thread before that and close all initiators. This way, QuickFix/J will end up not really retrying to reconnect.

```
import java.io.InputStream
import java.util.Locale
import scala.util.control.NonFatal
import quickfix._
import quickfix.field._

class SimpleConnection(val configInputStream: InputStream,
                       val messageFactory: quickfix.MessageFactory)
  extends MessageCracker
    with quickfix.Application {

  private val locale = Locale.getDefault.getCountry
  private val settings = new SessionSettings(configInputStream)
  private val storeFactory = new FileStoreFactory(settings)
  private val loggerFactory = new QuickfixLoggerFactory(settings)

  private var initiatorOption: Option[SocketInitiator] = None
  private var sessionOption  : Option[SessionID] = None
  private var senderSeqOption: Option[Int] = None
  private var targetSeqOption: Option[Int] = None

  override def onLogout(sessionId: SessionID): Unit = {
    log.info("onLogout called for %s".format(sessionId))
    initiatorOption.foreach(initiator => initiator.stop(true))
    fireDisconnectedState // inform listeners
    initiatorOption = None
    sessionOption = None
  }

  override def onCreate(sessionId: SessionID): Unit = {
    log.info("onCreate called for %s".format(sessionId))

    val session = Session.lookupSession(sessionId)
    val interval = settings.getLong(session.getSessionID, "ReconnectInterval")

    if(interval <= 10)
      log.error("ReconnectInterval should be at least 10secs.")
    else {
      import java.util.concurrent.Executors
      import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
      val executor = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor)
      val monitor = new Runnable {
        override def run(): Unit = {
          val sleep = (interval-5)*1000
          Thread.sleep(sleep)
          if(!session.isLoggedOn) {
            log.warn("Killing QuickFix/J session before reconnection.")
            onLogout(session.getSessionID)
          }
        }
      }
      executor.execute(monitor)
    }

    senderSeqOption.foreach(session.setNextSenderMsgSeqNum(_))
    targetSeqOption.foreach(session.setNextTargetMsgSeqNum(_))

    senderSeqOption = None
    targetSeqOption = None
  }

}
```